# How do I get an Expo project to open on my Android phone?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

because Expo has been updated and won't open in a browser. I have no idea how to switch from lan to tunnel. I'm still using the Expo app to read the code from the terminal, but I keep getting an exception error. timeOut.
I therefore ask, "How can I open Expo Code in my Android device the same way we used to?"

Comment: Can you log the error here?

Comment: yes, just now i am scanning the qr code printed on terminal through my phone and its opening this url http://192.168.0.122:19000/_expo/loading in my android chrome
i also tried adding url manually in expo app starting with exp://192.168.0.122:19000, it gives me this error : '' uncaught error : java.net.socketTimeoutException : failed to connect to / 192.168.0.122 (port 19000) from / 192.168.0.103 (port 43130) after 10000ms

Comment: Is your phone connected to the same network as your computer?

Comment: yes both are on same wifi

Answer (score 2):

to switch from lan to tunnel, use this cmd when you start expo:

```
expo start --tunnel
```

Comment: Yes it worked , thanks alot, also if we scan thru phone it wont work, we have to copy the printed path and paste it into the app's expo url

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour